# VB.net Use World Template to create word document

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm working on automation of the creation of a word document, the basis of the code is as follows.

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document

        'Start Word and open the document template.
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = True
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("C:\MyTemplate.dotx")
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("CustomerName").Range.Style = "John Smith"
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("CustomerPhone").Range.Style = "(123) 456-7890"
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("CustomerEmail").Range.Style = "Jsmith@mail.com"
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run the program I get this unhandled exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Item with specified name
>   does not exist.'

I created the word document along with the bookmarks:
Please help on what may be causing this error, or let me know if I'm being dumb and using the wrong syntax

Comment: use `.Text =` instead of `.Style =`. `.Style` is for existing styles like Normal or Heading.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Slai that work perfectly